# Can you use a specific address to store a variable in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I am currently learning assembly language and a project I am working on requires us to convert a c file into an asm file. I am trying to implement the for loop from the c file, and I am wondering if I am able to store the counter variable at a specific address. For example, if the counter starts at 0, can I do something like this:

```
mov dword [ebp-0x4], 0
for_loop:
cmp dword [ebp-0x4], ecx
jge break
...
...
inc dword [ebp-0x4]
jmp for_loop
```

Comment: Well, yes, you can store a variable in memory.  You'd probably want to make sure you use an address that isn't already being used for something else.  There is also the question of 'reserving' vs 'committing' memory (or whatever the unix equivalent is).  But perhaps the more important question here is why you want to store it in memory instead of using a register.  Usually counters are good candidates for this.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, assembling the code will tell you if your idea is totally wrong or not. If the "assemble test" passes, stepping through the code with a debugger will (usually) settle the question. For this specific question, both tests pass easily. For the definitive answer you can check the ISA manual

Comment: Keep it in a register.  It's easier and it's faster.  Loop variables in memory make your code slow unless the loop body is big/slow enough that an extra 5 cycles of latency won't make it a bottleneck.  (e.g. in a loop that's already big/slow and doesn't run faster than 6cycles per iteration in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CX register for storing loop counter.

Comment: Why `cx`? He can use any register he wants (except `eip`, and using `esp` as general purpose register would be extremely tricky (impossible for somebody who's just learning assembly) ... Also using `cs` or `ss` would pose quite some challenge to the programmer... actually `cs` is doable in ridiculous way, unrolling every step of loop into different code segment... :D).

Comment: Well, CX is known for being a loop counter. That's basically it. You are certainly right that he can use any register, but using CX is like using naming conventions, it makes life better :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. But accessing specific memory address depends on this address location. If this address reside in your program memory space it would be fine, other way you'll get segmentation fault.

For more information on x86, Intel 64 instructions and their operands you can refer to [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.html).

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you did set up `ebp` firstly to something reasonable, where `[ebp-4]` is reserved for your counter.

So either:

1) in your `.data` or `.bss` segment you have something like:
`counter: dd ?` and you do `lea ebp,[counter+4]`.

2) or you use the `ebp` as stack frame pointer (common usage in C compiled code), like doing `push ebp` `mov ebp,esp` at the start of function.

Then you should reserve the space for local (`[ebp - something]`) variables, usually the `mov ebp,esp` is followed by `sub esp,<size of local vars>`.

Without that `esp` adjustment the next `push <something>` will overwrite `[ebp-4]` memory.

BTW, it's usually good to keep values used in inner loop in registers, for performance reasons. But if you are running short of registers, and you use the counter only for loop, your approach is valid.